# I need to combine two results from a SQL select query

Tags: sql, union

I Have two Select queries that get results for two tables with the same column names.

```
SELECT 
    labels.langjrd,
    labels.id,
    labels.lcphrase 
FROM 
    labels 
WHERE 
    labels.langjrd LIKE 'FRE%'
;
```

and

```
SELECT
    labels.langjrd,
    labels.id,
    labels.lcphrase 
FROM 
    labels 
WHERE 
    labels.langjrd LIKE 'ENG%'
;
```

When I run the query I want to put all the results into one table.  I read about union query but when I tried it, it didn’t work.  I don't want to overwrite all the duplicate data I just want to have the second select results be added to the bottom of the first select results.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With `UNION ALL` you can combine results from two queries like this:

```
SELECT 
  labels.langjrd,labels.id,labels.lcphrase 
FROM 
  labels 
WHERE 
  labels.langjrd LIKE  'FRE%'
UNION ALL
SELECT 
  labels.langjrd,labels.id,labels.lcphrase 
FROM 
  labels 
WHERE 
   labels.langjrd LIKE 'ENG%';
```

You read about `UNION` which does a similar thing, but it filters out duplicate results. So it's similar as `UNION ALL`, but not the same.

But since you are actually querying the exact same columns from the same table, you can just put the two conditions in the `where` clause and split them using `or`. That way you will get all records that match either of the conditions.

```
SELECT 
  labels.langjrd,labels.id,labels.lcphrase 
FROM 
  labels 
WHERE 
  labels.langjrd LIKE 'FRE%' OR
  labels.langjrd LIKE 'ENG%';
```